# "Удовлетворяющий требования" или "удовлетворяющий требованиям". Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Например, какое из этих двух предложений построено правильно?

1. При проведении работ использовать антистатический комплект, удовлетворяющий *требования* технологического процесса.
2. При проведении работ использовать антистатический комплект, удовлетворяющий *требованиям* технологического процесса.

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:

При проведении работ использовать антистатический комплект, удовлетворяющий требованиям технологического процесса.

Глагол "удовлетворять" в значении "быть вполне отвечающим, соответствующим чему-л." является непереходным и управляет Д.п.